# Meta-analysis of indirect effects/mediation models

Tags: meta-analysis, mediation

I am writing up a manuscript with six studies (4 correlational, 2 experimental). All the studies test the same conceptual indirect effects/mediation model:

[image]

I'd like to conduct a "mini meta-analysis" (Goh et al., 2016) on these models, in order to synthesize an estimate of the indirect/mediated effect, $ab$.

Can anyone help direct me to relevant tools/ manual? I don't think the Goh et al. paper addresses this question (though I may be missing something). Thanks!

**References**

Goh, J. X., Hall, J. A., & Rosenthal, R. (2016). Mini meta‐analysis of your own studies: Some arguments on why and a primer on how. *Social and Personality Psychology Compass*, 10(10), 535-549.

Comment: You need to edit your question with more details for anyone to help point you in the right direction. (a) what is the Goh et al paper, (b) what is the model the primary studies are fitting (c) which aspect of that model do you want to meta-analyse (d) what is the scientific question (e) what information can you extract from each study about the model, coefficients, standard errors, variance covariance matrix of the coefficients? And anything else you think might help us.

Comment: I am voting to close this as unclear since the OP did not come back with any extra information.

Comment: If you keep it open, I can try to scrape together an answer by the end of the day. I know the Goh et al. paper to which the OP is referring, and have a response sketched out in my mind. For better or worse, I suspect questions of how to meta-analyze indirect effects will become more common, so it could be worth having some guidance available on CV.

Comment: @jsakaluk, it would be better for you to write your own question, one that is clear & asks for the information you think future researchers will seek, & then answer it yourself, rather than try to answer an unclear question that the OP has not tried to improve.

Comment: Happy to, if that's the consensus. Prefer to give OP a chance to revise (and unsure if 5 days is reasonable turn-around, for some casual users) before poaching what I think could be a useful question.

Comment: I am indeed a casual user and did not phrase my question clearly enough; I'll try to add more details and clarify. 
1. The paper I was referring to is 
Goh, J. X., Hall, J. A., & Rosenthal, R. (2016). Mini meta‐analysis of your own studies: Some arguments on why and a primer on how. Social and Personality Psychology Compass, 10(10), 535-549.
2. I conducted tne mediation analyses using PROCESS (model 4). 
3. Need to meta-analyze the indirect effect. 
4. The question is whether this indirect effect is consistent and robust.

Comment: @mdewey, I've updated the OP's question with the new information they've supplied. If you reopen it, I can provide an answer.

Comment: @jsakaluk now open again